# search the node using keyword in drupal

Tags: search, drupal

I have created a text box with button to search the node which has the key word given in text box.
Is there any possible to search the node in drupal 7 with custom search button and textbox which is in tpl file

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, I'd recommend using views exposed filter inside a block.
https://www.drupal.org/node/2018903